# Throttle Violation in Stack Exchange APIs

Tags: request, throttling, stackexchange, 400-bad-request

I'm encountering an error while using the **StackExchange** **APIs** for my project. The error message states:

> "Error: 400 - too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 83980 seconds."

The given time of 83980 seconds can be changed.

Is there a way to resolve this issue and avoid the throttle violation? Alternatively, if there is a paid version available that offers more requests per day, how can I upgrade to that version?

(It is also crucial for the project to run consistently without interruptions for 24 hours and without much delay)

Comment: The "contact us" link on https://api.stackexchange.com/ to team+api@stackexchange.com is probably your best venue for this.

Comment: You [should register on StackApps](http://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) to get a key. You can then make 10k requests/day to the API (compared to the 300/day without a key).